# PHP MySQL Load rows from the database that have not yet been loaded

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

How to load rows that were not loaded earlier with ajax without using id? Because sorting rows is not by id.

Comment: any sample code?

Comment: If your ORDER is set, you can base your paging on `ROW_NUMBER()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a LIMIT clause in your SELECT statement:

```
SELECT * from <table> ORDER BY <something> LIMIT <start>, <count>
```

For example:

```
SELECT * from myTable ORDER BY `orderDate` DESC LIMIT 5,10  -- returns rows 6-15 (LIMIT counts from 0)
```

You'll need to track the rows you have already returned. You might do this with a `$_SESSION` variable that stores the offset of the next row to return.

So if you've retrieved rows 6-15 as above, you might use

```
$_SESSION['nextOffset'] = 15;
```

then

```
$query = "SELECT * from myTable ORDER BY `orderDate` DESC LIMIT ".$_SESSION['nextOffset'].','.($_SESSION['nextOffset']+10);
$_SESSION['nextOffset'] += 10;
```

Doubtless the local SQL police will take issue with concatenating the variables, but in this case the variable data is entirely under your control, so it's safe. If you included a WHERE clause based on, say, user input, then you'd go to prepared statements.